# Two colors in text in css

Tags: html, css, colors, textcolor

Can we have text in two colors like:

[image]

For HTML:

I searched it but I got the answer for:-

[image]

Comment: look for the orientation of the gradient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short example of what linear gradient can do

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(green, red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>
The BLA BLA
</h1>
```

Comment: here withour gradient http://jsfiddle.net/UNm8H/